# Explode a list of URLs on php

Tags: php

I am trying to import urls from a list of URLS using the explode function.

For example, let's say

```
<?php 

$urls = "http://storage.google.com/gn-0be5doc/da7f835a8c249109e7a1_solr.txt
http://google.com/gn-0be5doc/1660ed76f46bfc2467239e_solr.txt
http://google.com/gn-0be5doc/6dffbff7483625699010_solr.txt
http://google.com/gn-0be5doc/ef246266ee2e857372ae5c73_solr.txt
http://google.com/gn-0be5doc/d0565363ec338567c79b54e6_solr.txt
http://google.com/gn-0be5doc/43bd2d2abd741b2858f2b727_solr.txt
http://google.com/gn-0be5doc/eb289a45e485c38ad3a23bc4726dc_solr.txt"; 

$url_array = explode (" ", $urls); 

?>
```

Considering that there is no delimeter here, the explode functions returns the whole text together.

Is there a way I can get them separately? Perhaps use end of url as the txt part?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: surely the deliminator is a line break ?

Comment: No it's not, sorry I put that to align the urls. In the document I have it's a bunch of xml files in a txt file. No apparent delimeter.

Comment: Then your delimiter is a space? Post the contents as-is.

Comment: The delimeter was infact a line break. Got it!

Comment: pesky invisible characters

Comment: just like Unicode @Dagon

Comment: voted up, because it produced some very useful answers despite the fact that there was in fact a delimiter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like all you need:

```
$urls = explode( "\n",$urls );

or

$urls = explode( "\r\n", $urls );
```

if you must you could use `http://`

If it was a string with out breaks then:

```
$urls = "http://storage.google.com/gn-0be5doc/da7f835a8c249109e7a1_solr.txthttp://google.com/gn-0be5doc/1660ed76f46bfc2467239e_solr.txthttp://google.com/gn-0be5doc/6dffbff7483625699010_solr.txthttp://google.com/gn-0be5doc/ef246266ee2e857372ae5c73_solr.txt";

$urls = preg_split('@(?=http://)@', $urls);

print_r($urls);
```

explode not used as it remove the delimiter

Comment: Oops! Actually there was a linebreak in the original txt file. Your first suggestion worked just as I needed.  Thanks very much Dagon!

Comment: yeah... kind of thought that having urls bunched up, wouldn't make sense ^

Comment: me to, but not a lot of things do make sense,

Comment: stop making me use Google translator @Fred-ii- 
あなたはチーズの猫のように見えます

Answer (score 1):

You clearly have line breaks in your code, and for line breaks with/without extra whitespace, you can use `PHP_EOL` as a delimiter:

```
$url_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $urls);
```

Comment: He clearly has them in his code. I tested his code as presented.

Comment: well he did comment - but now retracted so uum - great

Comment: Got it sorted! Thanks Drakes as well.